# Relative vspace

Tags: spacing, relative

I have been searching all the forums and couldn't get an answer.

Is there any way to set a relative `vspace` in share LaTeX?

Lets say in my First page, I want my paragraph to start 5cm from top of the page and it also does the same for the second page.

Of course it will work with `vspace*{5cm}` but it's not relative since it only works if no input before `vspace*{5cm}`

So for example, if my first page is

```
\section{haha}
\vspace{5cm}
my name is.....
```

and my second page is

```
\vpsace*{5cm}
my name is...
```

The `vspace` will not be consistent since there is section name in the first page. Is there any way to make sure "my name is..." always start from 5cm from the top of the page regardless what is placed before the content.

Comment: Welcome, ShareLaTeX is irrelevant here and should not be taken into account while searching for a problem.  Apart from that, i doon't think i understand the question. Can you post a compilable small example and use that to explain what you want?

Comment: You have the `textpos` and `placeat` packages for such things.